# Swagger - Could not render this component, see the console

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, swagger

I am trying to set up a `SecurityDefinition` for Swagger. Unfortunately, when I run my app, I get an error, saying that it "Could no render this component, see the console", where the "Authorize" button should be.

There are quite a few posts on this issue, but I haven't found any which solved the problem for me. The odd part is that it seems to be connected to the `SecuritySchemeType`. Because this code actually renders the button (but it won't actually authorize, due to being the wrong type):

```
options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Scheme = "Bearer"
});
```

This correctly renders the "Authorize" button:

[image: Screenshot of the "Authorize" button.]

If I change it to `OAuth2` though...

```
options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2, // Now the button does not render anymore
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Scheme = "Bearer"
});
```

...now it gives the following error:

[image: Screenshot of the error message "Could no render this component, see the console".]

How does the `SecuritySchemeType` affect the rendering of the "Authenticate" button? And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Looking at the test code in swashbuckle for oauth it seems that you need to define an OAuth flow https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/test/WebSites/OAuth2Integration/Startup.cs#L58

Comment: @Ralf it seems that you are right. I still don't get why you need this in order to render the component though...

Comment: Does it matter? Or would you be happy when you get an authenticate button rendered but no authenticate functionality attached to it.

Comment: _"I still don't get why you need this in order to render the component though..."_ OAuth security schemes require different attributes (e.g. flows, scopes) than other auth types. When these attributes are missing, the generated OpenAPI definition is invalid, which results in rendering errors in Swagger UI.